# Locked Anti Phase PWM and BLDC makes sense?

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

Locked Anti Phase PWM is used to drive brushed DC Motors,
but does it make sense to use it for a BLDC, e.g. 3 Phase Motor?

Answer (score 0):

> *but does it make sense to use it for a BLDC, e.g. 3 Phase Motor?*

No, it doesn't make complete sense because, in a three phase motor drive, one half of each of the three H bridge drives can remain at DC bus voltage or bus ground per AC half cycle and hence you reduce switching losses. Preferred way at the top: -

[image]

You can still drive the motors with anti-phase PWM if you want but the losses will be greater for no clear benefit.